# What's the proper syntax for focus() inside setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, focus, settimeout

I want to give focus to an input element right after I display its parent div. For that, I need to set a small timeout, or else the element won't be able to receive focus. However, I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
window.setTimeout(setFocus,100); // setFocus defined elsewhere
```

works, but I don't want to create a function for that.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myInput').focus(); },100);
```

works, but I don't want to create an inline function, either.

```
window.setTimeout(document.getElementById('myInput').focus(),100);
```

doesn't work. No log.

```
window.setTimeout(document.getElementById('myInput').focus,100);
```

doesn't work. Log says: `Uncaught TypeError: 'focus' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.` What does that mean, and why am I getting this message?

Just to be sure:

```
window.setTimeout(console.log,100,'test');
```

works, meaning the proper way to call an object method inside setTimeout is without parenthesis. So, why do I get the above error?

Comment: Properly binding the `focus()` method should probably solve the issue - ie pass `document.getElementById('myInput').focus.bind(document.getElementById('myInput'))` to `setTimeout()`. However, I'm a bit confused since I'm reading that `getElementById()` actually returns an `Element` type - which is a supertype of the `HTMLElement` type raised in the error message.

Comment: @IAmDranged I'm confused too. And even if this binding works, it would make the code larger than the current one, so I'm not for it. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `focus` method is inherited from HTMLInputElement and is only bound to an object instance when you explicitly call it from the instance.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<script>
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

// the `focus` method is a function shared among all
// instances of HTMLInputElement
console.log(myInput.focus === myInput.constructor.prototype.focus); // true
console.log(myInput.focus === HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus) // true

// HTMLInputElement implements and in fact extends HTMLElement.
// The following explains the relationship between the
// three objects:
console.log(myInput instanceof HTMLInputElement); // true, instantiation of class
console.log(HTMLInputElement.prototype instanceof HTMLElement); // true, class inheritance

// this means that calling `setTimeout(myInput.focus, 100)` is
// the same as calling `setTimeout(HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus, 100)`.
// The solution is binding the method to an instance, like
// the following:
const focusMyInput = HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus.bind(myInput);
setTimeout(focusMyInput, 100);

// note that `HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus.bind(myInput)`
// is exactly the same as `myInput.focus.bind(myInput)`, but I
// prefer the former because it's clear what is happening,
// even though the latter reads a bit better. Also, when
// you write the code, make sure to drop a comment
// explaining what's going on and a link to my answer :)
// That will help the reader. I've known this "many times"
// over the years, meaning that I end up scratching my
// head over and over because it's tricky. A comment to
// your future self is the best.

// Also, calling `myInput.focus()` works because what happens
// is that `myInput.focus` function is retrieved and bound
// to `myInput` at runtime. This doesn't happen if you pass
// around the reference to the function itself, because it's
// like passing around `HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus`.
// The JavaScript engine binds functions for you when you
// directly call them from an object instance.

</script>
```